Multi-Conditional Xlookup with spill array inputs
I have an array with several columns that are spill ranges. I need to use each column to do a multi-conditional xlookup (or similar formula/result) that gives a spill range of the results. I used a sumifs to get results but when a cell is empty I would like it to remain empty, where the sumifs results gives 0% when a cell is empty.
The real application of this will be put into a LET formula and each of the spills in the xlookup is a choosecols output.
=XLOOKUP(1,($C$3#=$C$12:$C$15)*($D$3#=D12:D15),$E$12:$E$15,"",0)
=SUMIFS($E$12:$E$15,$C$12:$C$15,C3#,$D$12:$D$15,D3#)
In the image the borders denote a spill array. Expected results are manually entered.


You could try using the following formula:


=MAP(C3#,D3#,LAMBDA(α,δ, 
 XLOOKUP(1,(α=C12:C15)*(δ=D12:D15),
 IF(E12:E15="","",E12:E15),"")))


Or,
=LET(a, E12:E15, IF(a="","",SUMIFS(a,C3#,C12:C15,D3#,D12:D15)))


Or,
=LET(
     a, FILTER(E12:E15,COUNTIFS(C3#,C12:C15,D3#,D12:D15)),
     IF(a="","",a))


Or,
=XLOOKUP(C3#&"|"&D3#,C12:C15&"|"&D12:D15,IF(E12:E15="","",E12:E15))



The map formula worked, although the performance in my application is pretty slow

What abt this one: =LET(      a, FILTER(E12:E15,COUNTIFS(C3#,C12:C15,D3#,D12:D15)),      IF(a=0,"",a))

The logic isn't if it's 0 make it blank, a true 0 we want to display. It's if it's empty we want it to remain empty.

Ah Gotcha: =IF(E12:E15="","",SUMIFS(E12:E15,C3#,C12:C15,D3#,D12:D15)) just change the 0 to ""

Does the sorting matter for that? For example, if the summary is resorted and I'm pulling the values from an unsorted dataset, won't those blanks be in the wrong positions?

After testing it seems to keep the location blank regardless of what the match is.

I don think sorting should matter here. Because the output you need is to keep those which are blanks as blanks, while the one with 0 to be shown as 0, so the sorting wont' effect here

I mean if the bottom array stays as is, but the top array gets resorted, will the blank stay in it's absolute position or adjust to where it's supposed to be? From what I saw it seemed to stay in it's absolute place regardless what the sumifs would've pulled.

I have not found any difference though, it work as is.

So redid my own example and am seeing the results are incorrect using the IF( [range] = "" logic. Where the blank is an absolute position where the summary is resorted and the results are also not displaying the right values. I'll stick to Map for now

to give credit where it's due, I tried a few other examples and your final one in your answer with the &"|"& component worked the best and could handle resorting the data source without sacrificing the null values or accuracy of the results. Well done.

Sounds Great!! Thanks for sharing the feedback. It helps!

No problem, my goal is to make sure things get resolved effectively so it's important to me to document which solution worked most effectively.

Would this work Mark?
=IF(LEN(TRIM($E$12#)), SUMIFS($E$12#,$C$12#,C3#,$D$12#,D3#),"")


Or

